# Displaying a specific field in a django form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have the following field in a django form:

```
position = forms.ModelChoiceField(Position.objects.order_by('-ordering'),
                                    empty_label='Select Position',)
```

In my `Position` model, I am using the `unicode` field to display the field called "position". However, in this particular form, I want the output to be a different field in the model called "position-select". How would I do this **without** altering the default output of the `unicode` field?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to display the "position" field with the __unicode__ description from "position-select"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try "subclassing ModelChoiceField and override label_from_instance", per the example at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield. You could specify a reference to the `__unicode__` function of your other field within that overridden class.

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked:

```
class PositionSelect(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.select_display

class Position(forms.Form):
    position = PositionSelect(Position.objects.order_by('-ordering'),
                                    empty_label='Select Position',)
```

Answer (score 0):

In one line inside the **init** method of your Form :

```py
self.fields['position'].label_from_instance = lambda obj: f"{obj.position_select}"
```