# Display field other than __str__

Tags: django, django-forms, modelchoicefield

I am trying to display the version field from the below model other than the default **str** which is field2_name:

Note: This SO link [Displaying a specific field in a django form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629323/displaying-a-specific-field-in-a-django-form) might be more than I need but I am not 100% sure. I tried to implement this but was not successful.

Also note that I tried the example at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/fields/ but was not able to get it to work

Model (Generic names):

```
class CodeVersion(models.Model):
field1= models.ForeignKey(SomeOtherModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
field2_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
field3_description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
version = models.PositiveIntegerField()

def __str__(self):
  return self.field2_name
```

Form:

```
class VersionsForm(forms.Form):

code_versions = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=CodeVersion.objects.none())

def __init__(self, SomeOtherModel_id):
   super(VersionsForm, self).__init__()
   self.fields['infocode_versions'].queryset = CodeVersion.objects.filter(SomeOtherModel_id=SomeOtherModel_id)
```

This works - it returns field2_name as it is supposed to.

How do I return version instead - what is the simplest way?

Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

From the [`ModelChoiceField` docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield):

> The `__str__` (`__unicode__` on Python 2) method of the model will be called to generate string representations of the objects for use in the field’s choices; to provide customized representations, subclass `ModelChoiceField` and override `label_from_instance`. This method will receive a model object, and should return a string suitable for representing it. For example:
>
> ```
> from django.forms import ModelChoiceField
>
> class MyModelChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
>     def label_from_instance(self, obj):
>         return "My Object #%i" % obj.id
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried a version of this (see 1st SO link) and I was unable to get it to work. It is possible that I did it incorrectly though. I will look at this specific example today. The truth is I am not really clear on exactly what is happening in this example but I will "dig in". :)

Comment: Gave you +1 - please see comment I made to iklinac.

Answer (score 3):

If I got your question correctly you could change object string representation

```
def __str__(self):
  return str(self.version)
```

You could then inherit ModelChoiceField and override label_from_instance method

or even monkey patch it like this

```
self.fields['field_name'].label_from_instance = self.label_from_instance

@staticmethod
def label_from_instance(self):
    return str(self.value)
```

Comment: Thank you for responding :) Unfortunately I can't change the str for this particular model.

Comment: You could then inherit ModelChoiceField and override label_from_instance method

Comment: Thank you - I will look further in to label_from_instance and your ideas today.

Comment: Turns out I was able to change the str to what I needed - it wasn't being used yet. I will have to put this on the back burner as I am sure this will be needed in the future. Gave you +1.

Comment: @iklinac is there a way to write the monkey patch method all in one line? For example incorporate the `label_from_instance` routine in the right hand side of `self.fields['field_name'].label_from_instance = self.label_from_instance`

Comment: @Ibo use lambda: `self.fields['field_name'].label_from_instance = lambda obj: str(obj.value)`

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way in this case that I struggled myself:

under your line of code

```
self.fields['infocode_versions'].queryset = CodeVersion.objects.filter(SomeOtherModel_id=SomeOtherModel_id)
```

insert this:

```
self.fields["infocode_versions"].label_from_instance = lambda obj: "%s" % obj.version
```

Answer (score 0):

In one line :

```py
self.fields['code_versions'].label_from_instance = lambda obj: f"{obj.version}"
```

Complete example

```py
class VersionsForm(forms.Form):

    code_versions = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=CodeVersion.objects.none())
    
    def __init__(self, SomeOtherModel_id):
       super().__init__()
       self.fields['code_versions'].queryset = CodeVersion.objects.filter(SomeOtherModel_id=SomeOtherModel_id)
       self.fields['code_versions'].label_from_instance = lambda obj: f"{obj.version}"
```